# Using Cognito Authentication with Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: java, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-elb

I have a ReactJS front end website which uses AWS Cognito for authentication, this is working fine, I can sign in, up, out, etc.  My back end is a set of Java web services running in Docker containers in AWS Fargate all behind an Elastic Load Balancer.

I noticed that in the ELB, you can add Authentication to the listeners which will check the HTTP header for the jwt token and authenticate it before forwarding to the relevant micro service.  I've come a cross an issue where when I set the 'Authenticate...' rule, it comes back with an error that I need to add a client secret.  I can't add a client secret to my Cognito setup because I'm accessing it from ReactJS and apparently Javascript doesn't work with Cognito with Client Secret added.

So if I can't use this method, I need some way of authenticating HTTPS requests when they get to my Java microservices.  From my Java service, it feels like I need to somehow access AWS Cognito to check the user session but that feels wrong.

Any ideas how this should work?

Thanks

Comment: How about creating another app client for ALB?, What was your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to use `pure JS` to authenticate with AWS Cognito without client secret which is an optional. I did create a `App Client` without `Client Secret` and it did work.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication.html

```
// Amazon Cognito creates a session which includes the id, access, and refresh tokens of an authenticated user.

var authenticationData = {
        Username : 'username',
        Password : 'password',
    };
    var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
    var poolData = { 
        UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_ExaMPle',
        ClientId : '1example23456789'
    };
    var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var userData = {
        Username : 'username',
        Pool : userPool
    };
    var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();

            /* Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with identity pools or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer */
            var idToken = result.idToken.jwtToken;
        },

        onFailure: function(err) {
            alert(err);
        },

});
```

Also, as you are using `ReactJS`, you can try `Amplify`:

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication

I understand that while you have so many layers and sometimes you want to configure it as you want, you can try to make yourself a simple authenticating function with `AWS Lambda`.